# How to update aws redshift table via fluentD

Tags: amazon-redshift, fluentd

[fluentD plugin](https://github.com/flydata/fluent-plugin-redshift) is used to insert csv to redshift table, but i dont see update is possible with this? If yes, could you please help me point the steps/configuration.

I have already asked this question [here](https://github.com/flydata/fluent-plugin-redshift/wiki/FAQ), and waiting for the response.

If there is no fluentD support then is it good idea to write custom notification listener service where the service will listen for sql update request events in the queue and update the same using jdbc batch update ..?

Please suggest.

---

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=816020#816020

Comment: I imagine that fluentd will be generating insert/delete/update statements and issuing these to redshift. if this is the case then if your volumes are more than trivial - you will hit problems. please can you update question with some relevant info around this, volume expected etc.?

Comment: @JonScott I dont see option to set insert/delete/update in the fluentD plugin spec, hence raised this question https://github.com/flydata/fluent-plugin-redshift/blob/master/README.md. And you are very correct with your thought processes about volumes. But still fluentD has buffers and can update as batch.

Comment: so - can you use the plugin?

Comment: @JonScott Already using the same but i am not seeing the option delete/update over there. I am using that only for insert.

Comment: how would you know what to update/delete? is that a record type? or are you wanting to sync changes?

Comment: @JonScott Want to update a record/row in a table. And i dont want sync, want asynchronus db changes, hence chosen fluentD.

Comment: Did you find an option to update record?